# What is the best way to rename all the images in a folder in php?

Tags: php, image, rename

I'm new in PHP and would like to know how I can rename all the pictures in a folder in PHP.

I have a folder that contains different pictures all named :

```
- BBBOF1_0090_A.jpg
- BBBOF1_0090_B.jpg
- BBBOF1_0090_C.jpg
- BBDOTR_0070_A.jpg
- BBDOTR_0070_B.jpg
....
```

I would like to add a K in front of the name of each image and change the numbers 1,2,3,4,5... to a,b,c,d

In the end I should have :

```
- KBBBOF1_0090_1.jpg
- KBBBOF1_0090_2.jpg
- KBBBOF1_0090_3.jpg
- KBBDOTR_0070_1.jpg
- KBBDOTR_0070_2.jpg
....
```

How do I do it please? I tried with the rename function to add the K but for the part where the letters are replaced by numbers I don't see how to do it.

```
<?php

$path = $_POST['path'];


   $dir    = $path;
   $allFiles = scandir($dir);

   foreach($allFiles as $file) {

        if (!in_array($file,array(".","..")))
      { 
  
      $file = $dir.$file;
      $filename = basename( $file );

   
        $newname = "K$filename";

        rename ("C:/wamp64/www/KMD/Photos/$filename", "C:/wamp64/www/KMD/new/$newname");
        
    }


  }

    
echo "good !";
?>
```

Comment: whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Nothing wrong, the K is added in front but for the replacement of letters by numbers I do not see ... And I was wondering if there was the possibility to rename directly without moving the files @GiacomoM

Comment: _"change the numbers 1,2,3,4,5... to a,b,c,d"_ Except your example of what you want in the end shows it the other way around: A,B,C gets changes to 1,2,3. Which is it: letters change to numbers, or numbers change to letters?

Comment: What do you mean by "rename directly without moving the files?" What's wrong with the `rename()` function?

Comment: Letters become numbers, sorry if I inverted

Comment: What have you tried to make the replacing work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The rename function deletes photos from one folder to put them in another, just if it could be done in the same folder or not?

Comment: I had tried this:
 $str = file_get_contents( $file );
$str = str_replace( 'A', '1', $str );

But it didn't work

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will get the contents of the file. It has nothing to do with the filename. Also, `rename()` works in the same folder if the source and destination folders are the same. E.g. `rename('/foo/bar.jpg', '/foo/baz.jpg')` will operate in the same directory (`/foo`). So this is exactly what you want.

Comment: How many different letters are possible? A-D, or A-Z?

Comment: Thank you for your explanations I understand better now. There can be the letters from A to J but I want to keep only the pictures from 1 to 6 so from A to F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be an easier way to do this but here is one way:

```
$newname = "K$filename"; // Start from here
preg_match( '/_([A-Z])\.jpg/', $newname, $matches ); // Get last letter
$char = ord($matches[1])-ord('A')+1; // Turn letter into corresponding number (A->1, B->2, etc.)
$newname = preg_replace( '/_([A-Z])\.jpg/', "_".$char, $newname ); // Replace letter with number
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, is to simply replace `_A` with `_1` etc

```
<?php
$files = [
    'BBBOF1_0090_A.jpg',
    'BBBOF1_0090_B.jpg',
    'BBBOF1_0090_C.jpg',
    'BBDOTR_0070_A.jpg',
    'BBDOTR_0070_B.jpg'
];

$replacers = [
    array_map(fn($v) => '_'.$v, range('A', 'Z')), 
    array_map(fn($v) => '_'.$v, range(1, 26))
];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo 'K'.str_replace($replacers[0], $replacers[1], $file).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result

```
KBBBOF1_0090_1.jpg
KBBBOF1_0090_2.jpg
KBBBOF1_0090_3.jpg
KBBDOTR_0070_1.jpg
KBBDOTR_0070_2.jpg
```

See online: https://3v4l.org/BBArn

Comment: Thanks, but I have an error with your code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' in

Comment: update php or change each `fn($v) => '_'.$v` to `function($v){return '_'.$v;}`

Comment: yep, as said change `fn($v) => '_'.$v` to `function($v){return '_'.$v;}`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the bug! But now the images are stored in an array, if I want to adapt my code to the real images in my folder?

Comment: I left that out as its not the issue and wouldn't help future readers to add in your code, all you need to do is implement the 3 lines above into your code/loop.

Comment: Are you talking about the 3 lines of kmoser?

Comment: whats kmoser? I meant the 2/3 lines from my answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand. I just need to use the $replacers table to adapt your code to my situation at the time

Comment: It's a big solution with array_map().... tested it worked.